# Changing the geom_* in ggplot2 by group (e.g. one group is line, next group is point)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to not only have the color changed by group, but also the "geometry" (geom_) . Something like `ggplot(aes(x,y,group=gr, geom=gr))`. Below is a workaround to show what I want to achieve. Is there a more elegant way (and btw the legend is not ok either)?

```
library(tidyverse)
df  <- purrr::cross_df(list(x=-25:25, gr=1:4)) %>% mutate(y=(0.1*x)^gr, gr=as.factor(gr))
df %>% ggplot(aes(x, y, group=gr, color=gr)) + 
     geom_point(data=df %>% filter(gr==1)) +
     geom_line(data=df %>% filter(gr==2 | gr==3)) +
     geom_step(data=df %>% filter(gr==4)) + theme_gray(18)
```

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How should the function know which geoms you like? I guess youve got many groups? And would a basic for-loop an option?

Comment: Well it could analogue to `scale_shape_manual` or so. No not soo many groups, but isn't the code ugly and "anti-tidyr"? Actually in my real example I first make the data long format to be able to use elegant ggplot strategy and then I am stuck...

Answer (score 1):

This would do your job

```
# define the different geom functions you want to use
funs <- rep_len(c(geom_point, geom_line, geom_step),
                df$gr %>% unique() %>% length())

# initialize the plot
gg <- df %>% ggplot(aes(x, y, group=gr, color=gr))

# define a counter
j <- 1

# iterate over the groups
for (i in df$gr %>% unique()) {
  # extend your plot with additional layers
  gg <- gg + 
    funs[[j]](data = df %>% filter(gr == i))
  j <- j + 1
}
gg
```

Comment: Thanks, not really so happy with it, but so it seems there is no easy way to do it...

Comment: well you could avoid the for loop with lapply/map and stuff so it would look nicer but, at least as I am aware of, there is no built in way in ggplot.